# Applying Template to all Charts in PowerPoint

Tags: templates, charts, powerpoint

Is there a technique for applying a chart template to ALL charts within a PowerPoint file? Applying a template one-by-one is time consuming when presentations include 40+ charts for each file.

Answer (score 0):

For each shape that's a chart, call the .ApplyChartTemplate method and pass the name of the template you want to apply as a parameter.